# Serial Fortran code with openMPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, serial-processing

I'm a newbie to parallel computing.

I have to run a legacy fluid dynamics Fortran 77 code. The program is serial and runs slowly, so I was wondering about the possibility to make it run parallel (e.g. by using open MPI), without deepening into the code. Is it possible?

Comment: Thinking of (someone else's) code as a "black box" is a terrible idea.

Comment: I think this question is much too general for this site

Answer (score 1):

You will have to deepen into the code. Some stuff can be calculated in parallel, some stuff needs synchronization. Parallelizing compilers and frameworks help identifying what depends on what, what can be parallelized, and what needs to be serialized, but as they can only read your code, and don't know about what you're modeling, it's still you who has to do the hard part of the work.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. The program performs a DNS for a channel flow.